# Rails routing error for sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm all of a sudden getting a routing error:

```
Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

Here is the output of rake routes:

```
signout DELETE /signout(.:format)                          sessions#destroy
```

And here is the view:

```
<li><%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
```

Any ideas

Comment: Are you sure your JavaScripts are working correctly?

Comment: if not then include in layout <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

Comment: Strange issue.. ummm.. Please try with <%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, :method => "DELETE" %>

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044246/using-devise-in-rails-3-2-3-cannot-sign-out/11044274#11044274

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, method: :delete %></li>
```

Try delete as a symbol.